# When running RMarkdown script (output pdf) in docker, with port 8000 as endpoint, plots make with plot_grid get grey border around them

Tags: r, docker, ggplot2, r-markdown

```
# Geslacht
gsl <- ggplot(data = df_wwg, aes(ymax=df_wwg$ymax, ymin=df_wwg$ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=df_wwg$geslacht)) +
  theme_sb() +
  geom_rect() +
  coord_polar("y", start=0, direction=-1) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y  = element_blank(), legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.position=c(0.075,0.075), rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent")) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(label.position = 'right'),fill=FALSE) 

# Leeftijd
lft <- ggplot(data = df_wwl, aes(ymax=df_wwl$ymax, ymin=df_wwl$ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=df_wwl$leeftijd)) +
  theme_sb() +
  geom_rect() +
  coord_polar("y", start=0, direction=-1) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y  = element_blank(), legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.position=c(0.075,0.075), rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))+
  guides(color=guide_legend(label.position = 'right'),fill=FALSE) 

# Opleidingsniveau
opl <- ggplot(data = df_wwo, aes(ymax=df_wwo$ymax, ymin=df_wwo$ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=opleidingsniveau)) +
  theme_sb() +
  geom_rect() +
  coord_polar("y", start=0, direction=-1) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y  = element_blank(), legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.position=c(0.075,0.075), rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))+
  guides(color=guide_legend(label.position = 'right'),fill=FALSE) 

# Duur
dur <- ggplot(data = df_wwd, aes(ymax=df_wwd$ymax, ymin=df_wwd$ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=df_wwd$duur)) +
  theme_sb() +
  geom_rect() +
  coord_polar("y", start=0, direction=-1) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y  = element_blank(), legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.position=c(0.075,0.075), rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))+
  guides(color=guide_legend(label.position = 'right'),fill=FALSE) 

# Put them next to each other
plt  <- plot_grid(gsl, lft, opl, dur, align = 'h', ncol=4)
plt <- plt + panel_border(remove = TRUE)
```

When I knit this code directly in RStudio, the output looks like this:
[image]

When I knit the code in a docker, with port 8000 as endpoint, the exact same code outputs this:
[image]

I tried all kinds of things, but so far nothing helps. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Some more info:

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
always_allow_html: yes
```

Comment: What if you removed `always_allow_html: yes`, I am not sure if it would change anything, but it shouldn't do anything if you are rendering to pdf_document

Comment: what is your code for the knit output to a specific port?